# Finding similar objects in different images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm developing a corporate logo image search system using **python3** and **image processing** libraries such as OpenCV.

So far, I have managed to extract individual objects from a given image, these objects are extracted as **binary images** so they can be easily used as masks.

This was done by **K-Means** clustering an image, using `cv2.connectedComponents` with 4 way connectivity, and then applying **Watershed** to separate objects.

```
# Making a binary version of the kmeans clustered image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(masked_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Euclidean Distance and Distance Mapping
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(binary)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, indices = False, min_distance = 25, labels = binary)

# Connected Component Analysis on local peaks and watershed algorithm
markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3,3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=binary)
print('{} components found'.format(len(np.unique(labels))- 1))

# Loop over unique labels
for label in np.unique(labels):
  if label == 0:
    continue
  
  # Draw label on the mask
  mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
  mask[labels == label] = 255

  # Detect contours in the mask 
  cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
  c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
 
  # Draw all contours
  image = cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
  cv2_imshow(image)
  cv2.imwrite("/content/watershed/contour{}.png".format(label), image)
```

Example:

**Input Image**

[image]

**One of the output objects**

[image]

My goal now is to find images in my dataset that contain an object similar to the rose above (not necessarily the exact same rose). Would this be achievable with an R-CNN? What other ways of matching would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options to do it. I put a list with few ideas:

1. Distance from histogram - you can compute the image histogram in the RGB channels, when each bin of each color will be a component of a feature vector, then you can measure the distance of the masked images and find all the image that are below a threshold.
2. Use a CNN as a feature extractor - take a pre-trained model (e.g. VGG16 trained on imageNet). resize the masked image to a fixed shape and use the model output as a feature vector. Then you can classify it with euclidian distance or other metric.
3. Template matching - you can resize all masked objects to a specific size and do template matching or MSE (or other technics) with the rose rotated in N angles. Here too you will need to threshold it.

There are a lot of solution, you should try some of them and compare them with a validation set.
Hope it helped